# What is the purpose of having a separate Layer property for sphericalMercator?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

The Beginner's Guide to OpenLayers 2.10 says the following:

> sphericalMercator {Boolean}
>
> This property determines if the map should behave as a
>   Mercator-projected map. Setting this to true will allow us to use
>   other layers, such as Vector layer, with the actual map projection.

Given that there is already a method where the projection is specified, i.e. in `map.projection`, why is there a need to specify the same thing over again in the `Layer` property? Is there a situation where a different projection is required in Layer as compared to the map?

Or do they serve totally different purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a shorthand for `EPSG:900913` and a number of zoom levels: [here's the relevant code in OpenLayers](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Layer/XYZ.js#L72).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have tested the code without specifying `map.projection`. By setting `sphericalMercator:true`, it does indeed return `EPSG:900913` using the `getProjection` method. This is useful, but doesn't fully answer my question why it is necessary to specify separately since I could have done that in `map.projection`.

Comment: Okay, to be more clear:  it isn't necessary - you can do one and/or the other. As far as specifying projection/settings in the map object or layer object, OL will check the layer object for a projection and then go to the projection on the map object. It's recommended to set all projection & zoom-level type settings on layers, so that you don't have configuration inheritance.

Comment: Wouldn't it be ideal if layer projection is inherited from map projection so that there is no need to set this in each layer? Is there a scenario where a different projection is required?

Comment: You can do either, but often layers will have more or fewer zoom levels. As soon as there's a "every layer has X but this layer has Y" relationship, it gets harder to track. I'd rather be explicit about configuration, but it's essentially a judgment call.